# Read contents of clipboard (with Flash or Java Applet)

Tags: javascript, flash, gwt

I've seen post that says its impossible to read the content of the clipboard. With the idea being your web app to read the clipboard.

How true is this? Is it that impossible to read the clipboard even if using flash?

How about having an applet jar loaded? Will it be possible now?

Comment: AFAIK java can read the clipboard content. It has a Clipboard class which [can be used to read the system clipboard content](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=82)

Comment: Im sorry what I mean was for web apps

Comment: @BackSlash that's not much help if he's trying to do it in GWT.